# Where to find JDBC URL in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, db-schema

I need to connect a Snowflake database to DB Schema. DB Schema is asking for the JDBC URL. Where can I find this in snowflake?

Answer (score 3):

If you are referring to this:

"jdbc:snowflake://--accountname--.snowflakecomputing.com/

you can find your Snowflake account URL by running this SQL:

```
use role accountadmin;
select system$whitelist();
```

Your Snowflake account URL will is as follows:
{"type":"**SNOWFLAKE_DEPLOYMENT**","host":"**xxxxxxx.snowflakecomputing.com**","port":443}

Comment: Note that the `system$whitelist` command is deprecated. The second line should now be `select system$allowlist();`

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough points to comment, so I'll steal from the best answer here IMO. system$whitelist is deprecated. The correct command is:

`use role acountadmin;`

`select system$allowlist();`

I've been pulling my hair out for an hour trying to get the correct JDBC URL into Datagrip.

Answer (score 0):

you should find it’s documented here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/jdbc-parameters.html

Comment: jdbc:snowflake://accountname.region.snowflakecomputing.com/?warehouse=DEV_WH&db=GEO